# module loading failing with ngRoute

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Just started learning angularJs and came across a 'Routing' assignment for practice. Unfortunately, I get these error when running the application:

Error 1:

> Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error

Error 2:

> Error: $injector:nomad Module Unavailable

This is my code:

[image: Routing.html]

And

[image: RoutingController.js]

I have tried reading other relevant post on SO but without luck.
I've been stuck here for too long so any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: You have missed a comma after your module name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your image, you have not defined the module properly, There should be a `,` after the module name to separate from the dependencies,

Your Module should be like this,

```
var app = angular.module(mainApp,['ngRoute'])
```

Comment: Think it's time for me to go to bed, haha.
Thank you it solved the problem :)